# How to get time values as strings, during read_excel execution?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, ods

i have to parse ODF-format turnstile's data file. In the file are employees entry/out time values in HH:MM:SS (like a 141:59:30).
[link to sample file on GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j0EEraI-JbfXKoaliXi_LV85S3_nIAk5/view?usp=sharing)

My attempts to open the file with df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine="odf", ...) had crushed with exception: ParserError
hour must be in 0..23: 141:59:30.

I tried to open file a several ways:

1. `df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine="odf", skiprows=3)` "skiprows" to cut useless header's rows.
2. `df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine="odf", skiprows=3, dtype=str)` "dtype=str" i thought, this option to represent all cells as string, to forbid automaticalliy datetime parsing.

But i haven't rid the ParserError exception.
Can you to point me a way to get values like a '141:59:30' as string at time read_excel execution?

Comment: this really is a strange behaviour... the only working option I found was to format the column in the spreadsheet to "text". it will appear as fractional days (e.g. "141:59:30" will become ~5.91 days). now you can load to df. in Python/pandas, you can then convert to timedelta if you like, with pd.to_timedelta and unit='d'.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a dictionary to the dtype parameter where you input your column name as the key, and the data type as the value.

Could look something like this :

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine="odf", skiprows=3, dtype={'time_col':str})
```

**UPDATE**

You could also try passing a converter function in the read statement.

```
def to_timedelta(x):
  return pd.to_timedelta(x)

df = pd.read_excel(filename, engine="odf", skiprows=3, converters={-1:to_timedelta})
```

Comment: it doesn't helps for my case. I tried dtype={-1: str} as the time-value column ever is last and have no name.
I'm asking the help here cause i have overtried many standard recipes

Comment: I have updated my answer with another possible solution. Make sure that -1 is referencing the right column, and not some extra blank column. Seems like you could also use column index 98, from your sample file.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help me.
ParserError exception is rising on df = pd.read_excel(...) string at once.
Function (to_timedelta) is never called.